# how to make an item slideUp automatically after specific time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

i have made an rss reader which takes feeds from a db and shows the title articles.The following code does this:
When a user clicks the titles(a.title) of the articles the content of the articles slideDown and appears.The content is in hidden class with the name content.When the user clicks the title again the content of the article slidesUp and dissapears.

```
$("a.title").live("click", function(){
        $(this).next("div.content").slideToggle();
});
```

How can i modify this part of the code in order in the first click the content of the feed to slidedown.In the second click of the title of the feed the content to slideUp?untill now the same functionality as i described.
But if the user only clck the feed once in order to appear the content of the feed and leave the feed with its content shown, after some time for example 2 minutes the content of the feed to slideUp automatically if no mouse movement notified.I tried to make that with setInterval function and mousemove but i couldn;t make it.Any ideas???Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("a.title").live("click", function(){
       setTimeout("alert('3 seconds.');",3000);
        $(this).next("div.content").slideToggle();
});
```

As of jQuery 1.4 you can use delay()

```
$("a.title").live("click", function(){
        $(this).next("div.content").delay(3000).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: So yot think that the mousemove function is not useful???And if the user in this code you just wrote slideUp the content in his own i believe that your code will cause the opposite(it will appear the content of the feed again??)Or am i wrong??

Comment: I tested the code you proposed but it doesn't make what i want.That it does is when i click the title of the link the content appears and after three seconds it appersan alert window which says that 3 seconds has passed and the same thing happens when i close the content of the article.The second approach of with delay function just delays to show the content of the link for 3 seconds.